# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence JPA

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting this error in my application JPA + EclipseLink with maven, I already added the dependencies of the persistence and eclipseLink api.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at ma.fstt.persistence.ProductOperations.\<clinit\>(ProductOperations.java:12)
    at ma.fstt.web.ProductServlet.listProducts(ProductServlet.java:51)
    at ma.fstt.web.ProductServlet.doGet(ProductServlet.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
```

This is my `pom.xml` :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Having dependencies in a POM can help with the compile and build, but they still need to be made available where you run the application classes - How are you deploying your app, and how are you building it, and what exactly are you executing to get this exception?

Comment: Thankyou for your time, but I resolved the problem by adding the .jar to lib directory